# How to view contents of JSON file? Data type error

Tags: json, decode

I am trying to view the contents of a json file but everything I use it doesn't load.

I tried many sites that claimed to be json viewers, extensions for browser, application and even when trying to edit in notepad++ it seems to be completely unreadble I am not sure if it's obfuscated/encrypted or if I am just doing the wrong thing.

I have tried googling many sources about this and have came to the conclusion that I am not aware of what "type" of json file this is and how to read it. Every application I have used gives data type error, which suggests it is only able to be viewed/compiled in a specific program / method.

I am wondering if anybody can help point me in the right direction! Below I will attach the json file contents

Warning: Large file may take a while to load in browser window

Example of code:

```
¦¦p­ÛâTÅbØ*«‹c—¤Î`¯²ÆSú0ÒEX…ÕÊh QDN ‘ùîó/8Ç³Ò©Ý¾ 4Ý(úk48Â–v¹Ôì¯úÓ„é…ƒº¯ÈŸ k"l¾NüžÏ¹úá¾Oð¹   )yà]ŒZš[>øÜáRÜ>¼ksÎÞT,èJ×Àåÿ;+\ LÙ ¯Ki5Uù×]åÁgp
```

I am sorry if this is not enough information, I am not sure what information is needed from me, I hope I provided enough, if anybody requires viewing the full contents of the json file to help further inspect this I would be happy to :) It is too large to upload to a site like pastebin or others